# When changing the text in an H1 tag in js, the new text stays there for only half a second, then goes back to the original text. How to fix?

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can I make the new text stay here? It's only there for a millisecond. I tried return false; in javascript. It sometimes removes default behaviors. That did not help. Query selector also fails.

```js
    function login(){
        localStorage.setItem("person1",document.getElementById("person1").value); 
        localStorage.setItem("person2",document.getElementById("person2").value); 
        document.getElementById('p1').innerHTML=localStorage.getItem('person1')+': '+one; 
        document.getElementById('p2').innerHTML=localStorage.getItem('person2')+': '+two; 
    }
    function submit(){
        var word=document.getElementById('word').value;
        var underscore='';
        for(var i=0; i<word.length; i++){
            if(i%2==0){
                underscore+='_';
            }
            else{
                underscore+=word[i];
            }
        }
        document.getElementById('underscore').innerHTML=underscore;
        return false;
    }
    function check(){
        var guess=document.getElementById('guess').value;
        var word=document.getElementById('word').value;
        if(guess==word){
            if(localStorage.getItem('person1')==document.getElementById('person1').value){
                one++;
                document.getElementById('p1').innerHTML=localStorage.getItem('person1')+': '+one; 
            }
            else{
                two++;
                document.getElementById('p2').innerHTML=localStorage.getItem('person2')+': '+two; 
            }
        }else{
            alert('Wrong!');
        }
        return false;
    }
```

```css
    input{
            border-radius: 10px;
            border-width: 1px;
            box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px blueviolet;
          }
          #p1{
              background-color: lightgreen;
            border-radius: 10px;
            border-width: 1px;
            box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px black;
            text-align:center;
          }
          #p2{
            background-color: turquoise;
            border-radius: 10px;
            border-width: 1px;
            box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px black;
          }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Guess The Word</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head><script>var one=0; var two=0;</script>
<body style="margin-top:100px; background-color:#ADD8E6; text-align: center;">
    <form>
        <h1>Login</h1>
        <input id="person1" type="text" name="person1" placeholder="Person 1"><br>
        <input id="person2" type="text" name="person2" placeholder="Person 2" style="margin-top: 10px;"><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" style="margin-top: 10px;" onclick="login()">
</form>
<h1 id="p1">1: 0</h1>
<h1 id="p2">2: 0</h1>
<input type="text" placeholder="Word" id="word"> 
<input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="submit()">
<h1 id="underscore">____________</h1>
<input type="text" placeholder="Word" id="guess"> 
<input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="check()">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Use `event.preventDefault()` instead of `return false`. Notice you were not `return`ing anything from `onclick="submit()"`.

Comment: @Deadpool Seen much worse code-dumps. The code is pretty straightforward really

Comment: I understand the first word field changes the H1, right?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.